# Angular js ng-click is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

While working on basic angular examples ng-click is not working as expected

the following is my html code :

```
<form ng-submit="requestFunding()" ng-controller="StartUpCalculator">
    Starting :
    <input ng-change='ComputeNeeded()' ng-model='funding.StartingEstimate'>Recommedation : {{needed}}
    <button>Fund me</button>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Javascript code :

```
function StartUpCalculator($scope)
{
    $scope.funding = {
        StartingEstimate: 0
    };
    ComputeNeeded = function ()
    {
        $scope.needed = $scope.funding.StartingEstimate * 10;
    };

    $scope.requestFunding = function ()
    {
        window.alert("Whoa!");
    };
}
```

whenever i click `Reset(reset())` button it executes `requestFunding` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thre is no `$scope.reset()` in controller. You are triggering the `ng-submit` by clciking the button.

You can change `<button>` to `<button type="button">` so it won't be bound to form submit. By default any button in a form with no type, and no click handler to preventDefault(), will trigger submit, however `type="button"` will not.

You also need to change `ComputeNeeded` to `$scope.ComputeNeeded` if you want it to work with `ng-change`

Answer (score 0):

Because on `ng-submit` you are calling `requestFunding`. Add a new button and call `requestFunding` from there or else remove `reset` from form tag and place it putside.